# Possible to make an OS X with a window that blocks a portion screen like the system menu bar?

Tags: objective-c, macos

Is it possible to create a NSWindow that will not only is above all other windows (including other applications) but also able to block windows from going "into" that window. Basically I would like to extend the system's menu bar by having another bar below it, but it stops the user from resizing other windows to occupy that space.

For instance, if the user was to maximize a window, it would only be able to have a height of the screen size minus the system status bar minus my application's window.

I was thinking it may be possible by listening to some sort of window resizing notification and if the user tries to set the frame of that other window to a size that would go inside of my application's window then I would resize the other window, but method seems like such a pain.

I also acknowledge that this may not be possible, but was curious if it is!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is totally possible to make a window which is above all other windows, just set It's level to `NSMainMenuWindowLevel`.

But preventing other windows from resizing beyond It, I don't think so.

Even if there is a system API to limit window resizing (I don't think there is), some apps use custom code to control window resizing and would completely ignore the presence of your "special" window. I've seen apps which simply hardcode 22 (the height of the menu bar) when calculating window resizing stuff.

Comment: Yeah, I knew about the level of windows, which is what I originally was doing, but obviously "maximizing" a window makes my app cover up the contents of the other apps. 

I actually ended up going with making an NSStatusBarItem that has a custom view, and just showing my content there, as it can always be viewed there.